# Hi there, having a bit problem in understanding the TypeERROR : "Cannot read property 'map' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I was trying to make a playlist project with react using Spotify developer tools and Api. Inside TrackList.js I am getting a TypeERROR "Cannot read property 'map' of undefined. Can you help me understand there the error?

```js
import React from 'react';

import './TrackList.css';

import Track from '../Track/Track';

class TrackList extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div class="TrackList" >
                {
                    this.props.tracks.map(track => {
                        return <Track track={track} 
                            key={track.id}
                            onAdd={this.props.onAdd} 
                            onRemove={this.props.onRemove}
                            isRemoval={this.props.isRemoval} />
                    })
                }
            </div>
        )
    }
}


export default TrackList;
```

Comment: `this.props.tracks` may not be an array

Comment: Map will work only with arrays, so make sure prop has array value. 
And also if its coming asynchronously then you can apply check like this this.props.tracks?.map

Answer (score 1):

The value of

> this.props.tracks

might not be the array, try this following code to render component only when value is array.

```
import React from "react";

import "./TrackList.css";

import Track from "../Track/Track";

class TrackList extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { tracks } = this.props;
    return (
      <div class="TrackList">
        {Array.isArray(tracks) &&
          tracks.map(track => {
            return (
              <Track
                track={track}
                key={track.id}
                onAdd={this.props.onAdd}
                onRemove={this.props.onRemove}
                isRemoval={this.props.isRemoval}
              />
            );
          })}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default TrackList;
```

Answer (score 0):

check your `tracks` array

```
 import React from "react";

import "./TrackList.css";

import Track from "../Track/Track";

class TrackList extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { tracks } = this.props;
    return (
      <div class="TrackList">
        {Array.isArray(tracks) &&
          tracks.map(track => {
            return (
              <Track
                track={track}
                key={track.id}
                onAdd={this.props.onAdd}
                onRemove={this.props.onRemove}
                isRemoval={this.props.isRemoval}
              />
            );
          })}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```